# Setting a column equal to the value of a subquery in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a 4-column table in postgres called `mytable`.  The fourth column - `batch` - contains only null values.  My goal is to update it using the `UPDATE... SET` commands by setting it equal to the result of a query that uses that table (in this case `NTILE(), which assigne each row to one of four equal-sized bins`) . For example:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET batch = (SELECT 
                    NTILE(4) OVER()
                    FROM
                    mytable)
```

When I try the above,the code fails with an error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

The query by itself runs successfully. How would one update this column with one command in postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the batch like this, then you need to use the primary key:

```
update mytable t
    set batch = t2.new_batch
    from (select t2.*, ntile(4) over () as new_batch
          from mytable t2
         ) t2
    where t2.pk = t.pk;
```

Note that the use of `ntile()` without `order by` is quite unorthodox, but that is how your question phrases the function call.